# Entity Framework: do I need to call db.Attach() before updating a record?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I came across this code snippet when I was reading a popular Entity Framework tutorial:

```
Student stud ;
// Get student from DB
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    stud = ctx.Students.Where(s => s.StudentName == "New Student1").FirstOrDefault<Student>();
}

// change student name in disconnected mode (out of DBContext scope)
if (stud != null)
{
    stud.StudentName = "Updated Student1";
}

//save modified entity using new DBContext
using (var dbCtx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    //Mark entity as modified
    dbCtx.Entry(stud).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;    
    dbCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

My question is: don't we need to call `ctx.students.Attach(stud)` before marking the entity as modified?

I know that `Attach()` just attaches the entity to the context, just as if it had been read from the database, and this is already done at the beginning of the code.

But in this code example, when updating the student, a new context is created. So it seems to me that we would need to call `Attach()`. Is it a mistake in the code? Or is it always unnecessary?

Comment: Not 100% sure (so not posting as an answer) but I think doing `dbCtx.Entry(whatever)` has the same effect as doing `dbCtx.Attach(watever)` if `whatever` was not currently attached.

Comment: So I think I should assume it's better to call `Attach()` before marking it as modified, even if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx):

**Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context**

```
var existingBlog = new Blog { BlogId = 1, Name = "ADO.NET Blog" };  
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Modified; 
    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

So, requesting entity entry from the context is also a convenient way to attach it.